# Can't find Lymith?

Tags: runes-of-magic

Not sure whats up, attempting to turn in the quest [The Important Chest](http://www.runesdatabase.com/quest/420521/the-important-chest) but Lymith isn't at the bank or near the spot on my map where it shows the quest is supposed to be turned in at. Why is Lymith not at the bank? or is Lymith somewhere else?

**Update**

So all of a sudden Lymith was there along with the entire Bank staff, whom I had never seen before. I had previously believed the only way to open my bank box was to go through my housemaid. It seems the bank staff are at the bank sometimes and most of the time aren't, what is going on?

Comment: idk what happened but when i started playing on my desktop everyone in the bank showed up, not sure if just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the Christmas event. They ended the event, but have not put the bankers back.